# Display Arabic font from website from textview in Android

Tags: android, json, textview, font-face, arabic

I want to display arabic content of a website, sent to me via JSON. My target devices are 2.1 to 4.0
Also do I have to look after anythings when sending data from server in JSON format to device.

Answer (score 0):

You should just make sure that your content is sent in UTF-8 format. Android will be able to display those Arabic characters.